# Shorter time interval for location updates

Tags: ios, swift, gps, core-location

My app is highly based on `CLLocation` timestamp. I found that `CLLocationManager` updates location in ~1s intervals. It's not enough for my app. Is it possible to configure `CLLocationManager` to update location in shorter intervals or should I look for other approach (timers + ask manually for location)?

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
}
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

timer + `requestLocation()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change frequency of updates. But you probably don't need that. You can calculate phone position by using `CMMotionManager` framework and you can get the user location using `CLLocationManager` framework.

Use `accelerometer` to calculate device movement. From `didAccelerate method` you can get `x`, `y` and `z` of move, so by applying this to detected user location you can calculate new device position.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: Can you please provide code for calculating displacement.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea how can I use `accelerometer` to calculate GPS coordinates. I need coordinates to check when the phone is in specific location. I need to check it as fast as possible. One second precision is not enough.

Comment: Anyway thanks for you answer. I will check what can I do with `accelerometer`. Maybe it will help.

Comment: I did some research and found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6M6wSLD-8M8. It looks promising but I think it will be complex to implementation. Thanks

Comment: The accelerometer data is usually so noisy that is impossible to calculate displacement from the acceleration values, you will need some very very sophisticated signal processing to get something meaningful out of it. I have tried doing that in the past and failed marvellously :-)

Comment: `CLLocation` as are provided by the `CLLocationManager` are enough to work with or not? Those `CLLocation`s have a property for `speed` and `course`, giving you both of the things you in one atomic set of data. The speed in meters per second and the direction in degrees. These values are also already calculated with the past values in mind of sort, with much less noise.

Perhaps these things are new? If they are then change the above to : "Hey look at these neat new features that make it a tad easier".

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the frequency of location update. The location service will only update if the value of [distanceFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423500-distancefilter) is exceeded.
If you want to force location update, try changing the value of distanceFilter (in meters, double data type). You can use [kCLDistanceFilterNone](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/kcldistancefilternone) as a value for distanceFilter.
Try like:

```
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
```

This code will force the location service to notify you if there is any small change in location or every movement.

Comment: As you can see in my post I am already using `kCLDistanceFilterNone` . There is still some time-depended limitation.

Comment: This fixed my issues!  Thank you, the kCLDistanceFilterNone gives much more frequent updates than a value of 0.  I appreciate your answer.